# Connecting Power Bi to protected Excel using a connection string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

I am trying to connect Power Bi Desktop to a password protected Excel file. I have looked online for solutions and everything points to the same conclusion. Power Bi does not support connecting to protected sheets. So I thought There may be another solution if I used a connection string and wrote my credentials but I could not get it to work.

Here is what I tried:

1- Get Data -> More -> OLE DB - > connect

2- I used OLE DB Provider 12.0 (also tried 16.0)

3- I put the path to my Excel and used the password in the data link properties as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yONpH.png)

I then get [this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFEWU.png) to enter the credentials. I tried `Password=MyPassword;` and used `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES";` because my file is macro-enabled but nothing seems to work so far and I get this error `OLE DB: External table is not in the expected format`

I don't know what user name to use in the credentials dialog since my Excel file is only protected with a password. I tried Admin, my Windows Username with Excel password and with Windows password and still did not work. I hope someone might point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe write a VBA routine that unprotects; refreshes the Query, then protects again.  You probably need to turn off background refresh on the query.